# How to notify Properties outside of an Object instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I am a WPF beginner and I have an issue with the `PropertyChanged` Events:

I have a viewmodel that contains an instance of another viewmodel. (I will use general names here)

**I want the instance of the `AxisVM` to notify my `SomeDouble` property. (Can´t use a converter)**

## edit: I didn´t include the full classes here, the `PropertyChangedEvent` is obviously implemented.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private AxisVM axis;
 
   public ViewModel()
   {
      this.AxisVM = new AxisVM();
   }
   
   public AxisVM Axis
   {
     get { return axis}; 
     set { axis = value; FireOnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

   public double SomeDouble
   {
     get { return axis.Lowerlimit * 1.5 }; 
   }

}
```

`AxisVM` also inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I use the ClassMemberName)

```
public class AxisVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double lowerLimit;

   public double LowerLimit
   {
     get { return lowerLimit }; 
     set { lowerLimit = value; FireOnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

}
```

In XAML I bind the Viewmodel as a DataContext (where doesn´t matter in this case I think) and then bind the Lower limit to a textbox.

When I edit the textbox, the event of the lower limit of the axis gets fired and the value is changed (view and viewmodel) but I need to notify my `SomeDouble` property because it gets updated when the lower limit changes.

The property changed event of the axis instance in my ViewModel never gets fired even though I access a property of it (which does fire its event but doesn´t notify my `SomeDouble` property).

I am at loss right now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at this [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)

Comment: You could use events for this. Or Binding both Ui elements to LowerLimit and using an converter (only if SomeDouble is only for showing in the UI).

Comment: There are often parent/child relationship. If parent needs to know about child, then typically parent will subscribe to child events. Public `Axis` setter is a problem, you have to unsubscribe from previous child there and subscribe to a new (or you can have memory leaks). Also parents may have to unsubscribe somewhere. Do you really need `public` setter?

Comment: Why is somedouble not in axisvm or lowerlimit in viewmodel? The purpose of a viewmodel is to adapt data and process to the view. Putting these properties in separate viewmodels seems to just make things harder.

Comment: @andy I would end up with one huge VM

Comment: So instead of putting the related properties in one or the other vm, what you've done is create a dependency. One vm needs to know about a property in another. This is something you should be avoiding.

Comment: Unfortunately the ViewModel has a property that is used in the calculation of the SomeDouble property that the Axis logically shouldnt have (the size of a canvas)

Comment: Maybe use inheritance? This architecture smells bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just handle the `PropertyChanged` of the `AxisVM` in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly AxisVM axis;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        axis = new AxisVM();
        axis.PropertyChanged += Axis_PropertyChanged;      
    }

    private void Axis_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FireOnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeDouble));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but is there not a cleaner way for doing this?

Comment: A cleaner way to hook up an event handler and handle an event of an object? No, I don't think so.

Comment: You should check for the property name in the `Axis_PropertyChanged` method, as it will get fired by every property, not only `LowerLimit`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an event for this.

Add an event in your AxisVM

```
public class AxisVM: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event EventHandler LowerLimitChanged;  

   private double lowerLimit;

   public double LowerLimit
   {
     get { return lowerLimit }; 
     set { lowerLimit = value; FireOnPropertyChanged(); LowerLimitChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
   }
}
```

And subscribe like this

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private AxisVM axis;

   public ViewModel()
   {
      this.AxisVM = new AxisVM();
      this.AxisVM.LowerLimitChanged += OnLowerLimitChanged;
   }

   public AxisVM Axis
   {
     get { return axis}; 
     set { axis = value; FireOnPropertyChanged(); }
   }

   public double SomeDouble
   {
     get { return axis.Lowerlimit * 1.5 }; 
   }

   public void OnLowerLimitChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      FireOnPropertyChanged("SomeDouble");
   }
}
```

You can remove `FireOnPropertyChanged("SomeDouble");` in your property `public AxisVM Axis` because this will only be fired when the instance of AxisVM is set and not when a property in this instance has changed.

Comment: PropertyChanged event is already available when you implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Not sure if @walkerbox means the same, but you don't need `LowerLimitChanged` event. Subscribe to `PropertyChanged` and check for `e.PropertyName` is either `nameof(LowerLimit)` or `""` (used to tell "all properties are changed").

Comment: I've done this, and I'll do it again. A consumer may only be interested in changes to `LowerLimit`. Adding a `LowerLimitChanged` event *in addition to PropertyChanged* is obviously not the only solution, but it's a perfectly sensible one. You can be too orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

When you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in AxisVM, you added `PropertyChanged` event there. Handle it in `ViewModel` and fire `FireOnPropertyChanged()`.

```
Axis.PropertyChanged += OnAxisVMPropertyChanged(...)
void OnAxisVMPropertyChanged(..)
{
    // Check property name
    // Fire OnPropertyChanged for LowerLimit
}
```

Comment: I am already firing the event in the AxisVm. When Lowerlimit changes, it does get updated in the UI. What I need is the instance of the AxisVM notifiying my SomeDouble property.

Comment: @d0neall: Did you see my answer? You should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `SomeDouble` property in the event handler.

Comment: Sorry. It works but I have several instances and I shouldn´t use too many events. Thanks though!

Comment: `is there not a cleaner way for doing this` - only my opinion, but for cleaner code check Messenger in MVVM Light lib. Allows you tu publish messages, where you don't have to have instance of publisher. Together with writing small ViewModels, that do not hold instances to each other, gives pretty good code.